# Get list of process filtered by WINDOWTITLE

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, exec, shell-exec, tasklist

I want to get the list of process of firefox which have a particular WINDOWTITLE.

I've succeeded to list them by using cron and batch file. Now I want to do the same thing but dynamically.

So I did this :

```
   foreach($TASK_LIST as $task){
      $out = array();
      $res = exec("tasklist /FI \"IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe\" /FI \"WINDOWTITLE eq $task\" /FO CSV /V",$out);
      var_dump($out);
   }
```

The problem is : I'm under Windows Server 2008 and the tasklist command (executed with PHP) doesn't return the WINDOWTITLE so the content of $out is empty. On my localhost it works fine.
When I write the same command on the terminal it also works.

I tried :

- with wmic but I can't filter by WINDOWTITLE with this
- Define apache user as current user
- Give rights to apache to interact with desktop
- "shell_exec" instead of "exec"

Any ideas or suggestions ?